# R: conditional expected value

Tags: r, statistics

Hello everybody (this is my first post in here)!

I'm having a problem with finding the conditional expected value for a given distribution.

Suppose that we need to find E( x | x>0.5 ), where x has gev (generalised extreme value) distribution, with density dgev(x, xi, sigma, mu). What I was trying to do was

```
library(evir)

func1 <- function(x) {x*dgev(x, xi, sigma, mu)}
integral <- integrate(func1, lower = 0.5, upper = 10000, subdivisions = 10000)
cond.exp.val <- as.numeric(integral[1])/(1-q)
```

where q is the value that gives qgev(q, xi, sigma, mu) = 0.5, used for normalisation.

The result greatly depends on the 'upper' parameter of integrate() function and for higher values of this parameter the integral diverges. As my distribution parameters are

```
xi <- 0.81
sigma <- 0.0067
mu <- 0.0072
```

this integration should be feasible and convergent. Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong or is there any built-in R function that may calculate such conditional expected value?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: My approach does not give the good answer. The question is: a) whether there is a built-in function for doing this and b) whether I make any mistake

Comment: What do you mean by a good answer?

Comment: I need to get the conditional expected value of a GEV distributed variable X under the condition that X > 0.5, i.e. E(X | X > 0.5). From the mathematical point of view it is done by integrating the product of X with the GEV density from 0.5 to infinity and dividing it by P(X > 0.5). The good answer would be a reasonable finite result of this calculation. I know how it works mathematically, I just cannot obtain it by using R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you are advised to use `Inf` rather than a large number when integrating the right tail of a density. See details in `?integrate`. I took your description of `q` as being a value obtained by iteration and I stopped when I got within 4 decimal places of 0.5 using `q <- 0.99315`:

```
qgev(.99315, xi, sigma, mu)
[1] 0.4998413
```

You also incorrectly used the extraction from your integral variable. Should use either "[[" or "$" when working with lists:

```
 func1 <- function(x) {x*dgev(x, xi, sigma, mu)}
 integral <- integrate(func1, lower = 0.5, upper = Inf, subdivisions = 10000)
 (cond.exp.val <- integral[[1]]/(1-.99315))  # `as.numeric` not needed
#[1] 2.646068
```

I have concerns that your description of how to get `q` was misleading, since values above 1 should not be an expectation derived from a statistical PDF.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't answer earlier, I was away from the computer. Thanks! Using Inf did the trick. And yes, usage of "[[ ]]" seems to be more natural. Apart from that, I seem to have not noticed that the function giving the "q" is just pgev().